# Combining classifications for multiple observations of a single sample in scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say I have multiple observations of each sample to be classified. Example of problems like this are:

- Multiple patches of a painting, where you're trying to classify the style
- Multiple windows of a signal, where you're trying to classify the signal

What is the most pythonic way to combine the answers into a single one?

p.s.: I don't want ensemble -- to combine the answers of multiple models taking as input a single sample. I want to combine the answers of a single model over multiple observations of a single sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want ensemble, but you can mimic best practices from ensembles. There are two basic ways to aggregate predictions:

1. **Arithmetic Average**, if your model does regression or probabilistic classification.
2. **Mode**, if your model does straitforward classification.

Of course, you can use any other summary statistic for aggregation.

The following code implements this idea with `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.tree
object_ids = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
x = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)
y = [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
# regression
model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor().fit(x, y)
prediction = pd.Series(model.predict(x)).groupby(object_ids).mean()
# probabilistic_classification
model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x, y)
prediction = pd.DataFrame(model.predict_proba(x)).groupby(object_ids).mean()
# 'crisp' classification
model = sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x, y)
def mode(x):
    return x.value_counts().index[0]
prediction = pd.Series(model.predict(x)).groupby(object_ids).apply(mode)
```

Comment: Didn't know `pd.Series` had these neat methods. I was writing something similar myself and it was getting pretty ugly (e.g. `model.predict(x.reshape(-1, features)).reshape(samples, observations, -1).mean(axis=1)`). Thanks.